# IIS application Alias

Tags: iis-8, asp.net-mvc

I have an application loaded on my default website

http:///AppName

now I have received a request for the exact same app, but to have the url "customised" for a specific customer . There is no actual value to this. just so that it looks special for the customer

http:///CustomerName

It is the exact same application.
Can I create an alias for the app name?

Other option is to add another App, and point it to the same folder. is that a bad idea? And if so, should they share an app pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options.

Assuming this is a web site for external use, you have a hostname pointing to the site. You could just add another hostname to the site bindings and both URLs will work for the single site.

As you already mentioned, you could also create a second site with the new hostname binding. There is no problem pointing this site to the same physical directory as the first site. Both sites can share the same application pool or use their own.

With the second option you have a few advantages:

- The web logs for different customers are nicely separated.
- You can have different configuration settings for both sites, even if they share the same web.config

A single site with two bindings is a simpler setup, you can always add a second site later one if you feel you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If the app uses authentication and will still be the exact same app as for the new customer then you could consider just adding a host header for your existing app.

IIS Manager > Click on website > Click bindings and add the hostname.